# Movie with a portal that leads into a black ship on a beach

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for the title of a movie I saw over 10 years ago.  The film is set on an island where a black ship is beached on the shore.  The protagonists are children who used portals to teleport.  Perhaps the children came from the real world and through a portal and ended up on that ship.

Comment: Children, an island, and teleportation, makes me think of the 1990s reboot of *[The Tomorrow People](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/TheTomorrowPeople1973)*, but I don't remember any beached ships. Plus, that's a series, not a movie.

Comment: Do you know where you watched it (theater, TV, online, rented VHS/DVD/laserdisc)? What language was it in? What was the ethnicity of the children? Do you remember any hair colors? Was this a sailing ship? A starship?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Reminds me a bit of [Magic island](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113736/), where kid is telepoted to the fantasy island, with mermaid and a [small] boat on the beach.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots They did teleport, but not by using portals.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I also thought of The Tomorrow People, and there is indeed a beached (space)ship on the shore - see the beginning of the pilot episode [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9q7e_qK-OmE).

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Ah, I hadn't thought it was visible, but rather buried underground. It's been a while.

Comment: I only ever saw the 2013 reboot of The Tomorrow People. Watching that 1992 version, man, that was seriously bootleg. I see why they threw all that out and wrote a completely different storyline.

Comment: I still see the 90s version as the "new" one :)